# Extra line returns in text boxes clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, clipboard, carriage-return

I have created a "Word Merge" routine that i use personally.  When I add items into my 3 text boxes, and then merge, everything looks fine.  but when i copy to a clipboard, there are extra carriage returns that I didn't see before.  Can anyone help?  I have attached the code and two images of the results below:

```
private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char[] delimiterChars2 = { ',', ':', '|', '\n' };

    List<string> listBox1 = new List<string>(textBox_MergeList1.Text.Split(delimiterChars2));
    List<string> listBox2 = new List<string>(textBox_MergeList2.Text.Split(delimiterChars2));
    List<string> listBox3 = new List<string>(textBox_MergeList3.Text.Split(delimiterChars2));

    string outputDelimiter = "-";            

    var result = from s1 in listBox1
                 from s2 in listBox2
                 from s3 in listBox3
                 select s1 + outputDelimiter + s2 + outputDelimiter + s3;

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        textBox_MergeListResults.Text = String.Join("\r\n", result);
    }

    Clipboard.SetText(textBox_MergeListResults.Text);
}
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with my delimiter splitting in the beginning, because if i just use the following, i don't have any issues:

```
List<string> listBox1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
List<string> listBox2 = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
List<string> listBox3 = new List<string>() { "Dogs", "Cats", "Pigs" };
```

Image of output results:  http://screencast.com/t/zu49GgOok1m

Image of clipboard results: http://screencast.com/t/SqmJqFmqT

Comment: Remove `\r` from the join and use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: Like this?  textBox_MergeListResults.Text = String.Join(StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries, result);  Visual Studio doesn't like it...red squigglies under the whole thing.

Comment: No, sorry. Remove `\r` from the call to `Join`. Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` in the calls to `Split`.

Comment: Sorry  I'm confused.  I have textBox_MergeListResults.Text = String.Join("\n", result);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Answered in chat after playing around with it.

Requires splitting on `\r` and `\n`. Then joining back with `\r` and `\n` too.

Comment: OK..I tried it, but still a problem.  The merged output is wrong when i get rid of the '\r' as seen here:  http://screencast.com/t/c9jFauEa6OEp and the pasted clipboard is still like the original problem..no change there.

Comment: I noticed your output doesn't have the `outputDelimeter`. Are you running different code?

Comment: yea... i was running optional delimters, but i just changed it to the code i posted above and same...here is output:  http://screencast.com/t/73k7vdgYZr

Comment: its like there is an added carriage return at the end of each item in each box.

Comment: ..can you show me a screenshot of your entire code as it is in the editor?

Comment: The code follows... BTW, i just changed the delimiter in the text boxes to ',' and it works fine...so maybe the '\n' is being stored somehow?  http://screencast.com/t/myzXcilRe

Comment: There appears to be no `Clipboard.SetText` there.. ?

Comment: Sorry, that was much further down in the code:  http://screencast.com/t/d73xB9sSl

Comment: that red is a glitch i just added when copying

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21293/discussion-between-jeagr-and-simon-whitehead)